# iOS 14 Widget is flickering or frozen, chronod crashing

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I've implemented a Widget Extension (i.e. an iOS 14 widget, using WidgetKit) for my app.  Ordinarily the widget works just fine, but occasionally it'll get into a state where it flickers repeatedly and eventually just freezes.  I've tried connecting a debugger to the widget process, but it doesn't catch any crashes or exceptions.  However I did see in my device logs repeated crashes (~25 over the course of one minute) in the chronod process.  The reports all look basically the same:

```
Incident Identifier: ...
CrashReporter Key:   ...
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,3
Process:             chronod [96919]
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChronoCore.framework/Support/chronod
Identifier:          chronod
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.chronod [443]


Date/Time:           2020-09-30 13:41:06.1434 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-09-30 13:41:05.6902 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.0 (18A373)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    6.02.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000197017d08
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [96919]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SwiftUI                         0x0000000197017d08 CodablePlatformFont.init+ 6647048 (from:) + 2744
1   SwiftUI                         0x0000000197017a00 CodablePlatformFont.init+ 6646272 (from:) + 1968
2   SwiftUI                         0x0000000197017d34 protocol witness for Decodable.init+ 6647092 (from:) in conformance CodablePlatformFont + 20
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000194548f80 dispatch thunk of Decodable.init+ 2957184 (from:) + 16
4   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162ccc __PlistDecoder.unbox<A>+ 326860 (_:as:) + 372
5   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000019416d820 _PlistKeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 370720 (_:forKey:) + 660
6   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000019416fc54 protocol witness for KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol.decode<A>+ 379988 (_:forKey:) in conformance _PlistKeyedDecodingContainer<A> + 48
7   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000019416f9b4 protocol witness for KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol.decode<A>+ 379316 (_:forKey:) in conformance _PlistKeyedDecodingContainer<A> + 20
8   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942cb2cc _KeyedDecodingContainerBox.decode<A, B>+ 344780 (_:forKey:) + 296
9   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942be9e4 KeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 293348 (_:forKey:) + 40
10  SwiftUI                         0x0000000197014374 CodableAttributes.init+ 6632308 (from:) + 832
11  SwiftUI                         0x0000000197015170 protocol witness for Decodable.init+ 6635888 (from:) in conformance CodableAttributes + 20
12  libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000194548f80 dispatch thunk of Decodable.init+ 2957184 (from:) + 16
13  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162ccc __PlistDecoder.unbox<A>+ 326860 (_:as:) + 372
14  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001941702ec _PlistUnkeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 381676 (_:) + 776
15  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194172110 protocol witness for UnkeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 389392 (_:) in conformance _PlistUnkeyedDecodingContainer + 12
16  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942d5bd0 Array<A>.init+ 388048 (from:) + 332
17  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942d6178 protocol witness for Decodable.init+ 389496 (from:) in conformance <A> [A] + 28
18  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942d5c8c protocol witness for Decodable.init+ 388236 (from:) in conformance <A> [A] + 20
19  libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000194548f80 dispatch thunk of Decodable.init+ 2957184 (from:) + 16
20  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162ccc __PlistDecoder.unbox<A>+ 326860 (_:as:) + 372
21  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000019416d820 _PlistKeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 370720 (_:forKey:) + 660
.
.
. (Shortened the stack trace for readability, lots more Plist decoding here)
.
.
153 libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942cb2cc _KeyedDecodingContainerBox.decode<A, B>+ 344780 (_:forKey:) + 296
154 libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001942be9e4 KeyedDecodingContainer.decode<A>+ 293348 (_:forKey:) + 40
155 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196bd0560 _ArchivedViewStates.State.init+ 2159968 (from:) + 304
156 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196bd08d4 protocol witness for Decodable.init+ 2160852 (from:) in conformance _ArchivedViewStates.State + 20
157 libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000194548f80 dispatch thunk of Decodable.init+ 2957184 (from:) + 16
158 libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162ccc __PlistDecoder.unbox<A>+ 326860 (_:as:) + 372
159 libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162a08 PropertyListDecoder.decode<A>+ 326152 (_:fromTopLevel:) + 344
160 libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000019416278c PropertyListDecoder.decode<A>+ 325516 (_:from:format:) + 296
161 libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x0000000194162658 PropertyListDecoder.decode<A>+ 325208 (_:from:) + 44
162 libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001941732f4 dispatch thunk of PropertyListDecoder.decode<A>+ 393972 (_:from:) + 20
163 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196bd1204 _ArchivedViewStates.state+ 2163204 (at:) + 416
164 WidgetKit                       0x0000000196973ab0 0x19693a000 + 236208
165 WidgetKit                       0x00000001969748d4 0x19693a000 + 239828
166 WidgetKit                       0x00000001969a4794 0x19693a000 + 436116
167 ChronoKit                       0x00000001b9999c34 0x1b990d000 + 576564
168 ChronoKit                       0x00000001b99b3d20 0x1b990d000 + 683296
169 ChronoKit                       0x00000001b99b47a0 0x1b990d000 + 685984
170 ChronoKit                       0x00000001b99b4944 0x1b990d000 + 686404
171 ChronoKit                       0x00000001b99b17c0 0x1b990d000 + 673728
172 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d22bdc ViewBodyAccessor.body+ 3546076 (of:) + 32
173 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196ff87ac closure #1 in DynamicBody.updateValue+ 6518700 () + 156
174 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196ff861c DynamicBody.updateValue+ 6518300 () + 1660
175 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d43d8c partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>+ 3681676 (_:) + 28
176 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6064 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update+ 20580 () + 484
177 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6474 AG::Graph::update_attribute+ 21620 (AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
178 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bfb678 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow+ 42616 (AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
179 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6c0c258 AGGraphGetValue + 228
180 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d32cc4 SubscriptionView.ChildAttribute.view.getter + 68
181 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d32ef8 SubscriptionView.ChildAttribute.updateValue+ 3612408 () + 520
.
.
. (Shortened the stack trace for readability, lots more AttributeGraph stuff here)
.
.
222 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6064 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update+ 20580 () + 484
223 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6474 AG::Graph::update_attribute+ 21620 (AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
224 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bfb678 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow+ 42616 (AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 380
225 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6c0c258 AGGraphGetValue + 228
226 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d3da50 DynamicPreferenceCombiner.info.getter + 92
227 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196d3dc00 DynamicPreferenceCombiner.value.getter + 168
228 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196b2cda0 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>+ 1490336 (_:) + 84
229 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6064 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update+ 20580 () + 484
230 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bf6474 AG::Graph::update_attribute+ 21620 (AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
231 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6bfb0f4 AG::Graph::value_ref+ 41204 (AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*) + 152
232 AttributeGraph                  0x00000001b6c0c2a0 AGGraphGetValue + 300
233 SwiftUI                         0x00000001972a5d38 GraphHost.updatePreferences+ 9325880 () + 52
234 SwiftUI                         0x0000000196e32528 ViewGraph.updateOutputs+ 4658472 (at:) + 100
235 SwiftUI                         0x0000000197212644 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render+ 8721988 (interval:updateDisplayList:) + 1316
236 SwiftUI                         0x0000000197211aec ViewRendererHost.render+ 8719084 (interval:updateDisplayList:) + 316
237 SwiftUI                         0x000000019735f528 _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews+ 10085672 () + 184
238 SwiftUI                         0x000000019735f554 @objc _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews+ 10085716 () + 24
239 UIKitCore                       0x0000000193609954 -[UIView+ 16935252 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2464
240 QuartzCore                      0x0000000193b099e8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
241 QuartzCore                      0x0000000193b0feb4 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1420980 (CA::Transaction*) + 520
242 QuartzCore                      0x0000000193b1b1d0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1466832 (CA::Transaction*) + 140
243 QuartzCore                      0x0000000193a67500 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 730368 (CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416
244 QuartzCore                      0x0000000193a91698 CA::Transaction::commit+ 902808 () + 728
245 UIKitCore                       0x00000001931217ac __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 80
246 CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190844fa0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
247 CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190844228 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 404
248 CoreFoundation                  0x000000019083ea54 __CFRunLoopRun + 796
249 CoreFoundation                  0x000000019083e200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
250 GraphicsServices                0x00000001a6939598 GSEventRunModal + 160
251 UIKitCore                       0x0000000193104004 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
252 UIKitCore                       0x00000001931095d8 UIApplicationMain + 164
253 ChronoCore                      0x00000001b92b23d4 0x1b922e000 + 541652
254 chronod                         0x00000001000ab6a4 0x1000a8000 + 13988
255 libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019051d598 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bb1a38c4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bb1a2cc8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019084474c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019083ebd0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019083e200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                      0x0000000191a48278 -[NSRunLoop+ 33400 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x0000000191a48158 -[NSRunLoop+ 33112 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001931af9fc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 504
8   Foundation                      0x0000000191ba4c48 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d6116b70 _pthread_start + 288
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b880 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d611b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001000d7200   x1: 0x0000000000000407   x2: 0x0000000000000407   x3: 0x0000000100384c40
    x4: 0x0000000000000020   x5: 0x0000000100384c40   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x091bc10038780055   x9: 0x091bc10038780055  x10: 0x00000000000bcfa0  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000100300000  x13: 0x0000000088c5e050  x14: 0x0000000088c5e014  x15: 0x0000000000003c93
   x16: 0x00000001d6106ef0  x17: 0x00000000d0411000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001deab4d20
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x00000001deb92018  x23: 0x0000000100384c70
   x24: 0x000000016fd4b640  x25: 0x00000001deaa3f50  x26: 0x0000000106771e00  x27: 0x0000000106771ea0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016fd4b760   lr: 0x0000000197017a00
    sp: 0x000000016fd4b630   pc: 0x0000000197017d08 cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

So it seems pretty clear that the error has to do with decoding a Font object.  I do use custom fonts in my app and widget which is likely relevant, but they show up just fine the first time they're displayed in the widget and I haven't had any issues in my app itself (which doesn't use SwiftUI).

It also looks like the process leading up to the error is the UI state being encoded and cached somewhere, then failing to be decoded for display later on.  But none of that code is owned by me, making it exceedingly difficult to debug.

What's going wrong, and how can it be addressed?

Comment: Would you add demo code? If you think that it is font - try to replace it temporary with system one and retest.

Comment: I'll see if I can produce demo code that produces the same result; I can't share the code I'm using right now (plus it's quite long).  I found one person who's posted a similar issue elsewhere and they reported that the error went away when they stopped using a custom font, so that does seem like a solid fallback option.

Comment: Update: I installed iOS 14.2 beta 2 last night and this error has not happened since.

Comment: I can confirm that temporarily replacing my custom font by a system font fixes the issue. It has also been reported here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660983. Seems not to be fixed in iOS 14.0.1.

Comment: Update your device/ simulator to iOS 14.1 and the widget flickering goes. This started happening to me as soon as I added a custom font to text on my widget with a iOS 14.0.1 device. The update to iOS 14.1 fixed it.